# How to divide the text html

Tags: html, css

I have some information about my site saved in a database, but the text is too long.
How can I divide the text at the end of the row?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="art"><!--HERE WILL APPEAR THE TEXT-->
    <p id="article"><?php
    require('fnc_secon.php');
    echo get_article();
    ?>
    </p><!--END--> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#art
{
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:50px;
    height:425px;
    width:410px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Thank you for the help and sorry for my English if I have made some mistakes.

Comment: Text in html automatically wraps at the end of the div's width. Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "divide"? Do you mean that you want to output only enough text to fit in a 425x410 container?

Comment: do you want a seemore script like fb???

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, the PHP is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is somehow not breaking on its own, you can force it with `word-break:break-all;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FXeYH/)**

```
#art {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:50px;
    height:425px;
    width:410px;
    background-color: green;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if you feel that it answered your question.